# Proving a set of equations is a subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have a set of equations $x + y = 0$ and $x - 2z = 0$ how do I prove these are closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: The equations or their solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The set $U$ described by the two equations is given by

$U=\{t(2,-2,1): t \in \mathbb R\}$. I think that is now easy to prove that $U$ is a subspace of $ \mathbb R^3$.